# Images not showing after adding const slider ... so confused

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, lazy-loading

So i've been following a tutorial and trying to teach myself next.js with lazy loading slider and tailwindcss.. I am a beginner but i have made ecommerce sites and stuff to teach myself.. but this tutorial was going great until this!but Ive tried everything i know and googled it every which way to try to fix this issue!! My images were showing perfectly before i added the - const setCurrent up to the if !Array

if i delete that the images show back up... im so confused ive gone through everything - also the "Gallery" even disapeared once i added that section
and i put it all on github incase someone can look at it to help me?? https://github.com/Jessica19882/firebird

i have deleted the
const current up to the !Array part and images showed back up i have tried rewriting it as another post said but that didnt work ive checked and zoomed into the video tutorial to make sure everything was right and it is... i have checked all the other pages index.js app.js and stuff to make sure i had it just like his and it is!!

slider.js

```
import { SliderData } from './SliderData'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Slider = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  const length = slides?.length

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
  }
  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1)
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div id='gallery'>
      <h1>Gallery</h1>
      <div>
        {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={
                index === current
                  ? 'opacity-[1] ease-in duration-1000'
                  : 'opacity-0'
              }>
              <Image
                src={slide.image}
                alt='/'
                width='1440'
                height='600'
                style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
              />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Hero from '../components/Hero'
import Slider from '../components/Slider'
import SliderData from '../components/SliderData'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Firebird Sounds</title>
        <meta name='description' content='firebird sounds' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>
      <Hero
        heading='Firebird Sounds - Audio & Video Distribution'
        message='Audio and Video Distribution with a menu of 
Services: Marketing, PR, Global rights management and creativity'
      />
      <Slider Slides={SliderData} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

SliderData.js

```
export const SliderData = [
  {
   image:
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466428996289-fb355538da1b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTl8fG11c2ljJTIwZGlzdHJpYnV0aW9ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
  },
  {
    image: '/images/FirebirdSounds.jpg',
  },
  {
    image:
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460667262436-cf19894f4774?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NjZ8fG11c2ljJTIwZGlzdHJpYnV0aW9ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
  },
  {
    image: '/images/guitar.jpg',
  },
  {
    image: '/images/firebird.png',
  },
]
```

app.js

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import '../styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR2jl5qYoIsaFZQ26MumbFcCYv5t3eYxcqVKgm4xAsxilhEkAzSNoUB0fzE&v=HVyct9EUNP8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hiya, can I suggest a couple things?  Link to the tutorial you are following, and instead of images of your IDE, copy the actual code causing the problem (not the whole file) to your question.  That way helpers can copy/paste into their own IDEs without retyping.  Also, link that other post  with the rewriting suggestion so helpers don't go chasing that solution again.  You'll likely get useful answers waaaay more quickly   :-)

Comment: ok i will do that!

Comment: Thank you I didn’t know how but I figured it out :)

Comment: Can you provide sandbox

Comment: Yes how do I do that I was trying to but couldn’t figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I needed to put the

```
Slider slides={SliderData}/>
```

into _app.js not index.js or both but its working again!